# Not being able to change version of python from 2.7-3.6

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying python --version in my windows subsystem for linux terminal and it is showing me 2.7.15 whereas I do not have 2.7 in my system. I have python 3.6 set in my environment variable, and that is the python interpreter I have used till date. Suddenly after restarting my system I could see that version is 2.7. How do I change  the version of python and set it to my original interpreter ? I have tried  sudo apt update && upgrade and then sudo apt install python3 python3-pip ipython3. Did not help.  Please help.

Comment: I think Python 2.7 is still the default in Ubuntu. Try running `python3` from the shell.

Comment: The problem got resolved. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try `python3 --version` or `python3.6 --version`

Answer (score 0):

Run these 2 commands

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv

virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python3 as `python3` or`python3.6`

If you still want to use python3 with the `python` command, edit your ~/.bash_profile file and add line `alias python='python3'` and restart terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `alternatives install` python 3.6
and try 
`# alternatives --config python`
and choose the alternative version